# Get truncated when insert data by stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

This is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROC InsertTINH
    @MaTinh char(4),
    @TenTinh varchar(50),
    @MaNuoc char(2)
as
begin
    if exists (select * from TINH where MaTinh = @MaTinh)
    begin
        print 'Ma Tinh already exists'
        return
    end
    else
    begin
        if not exists (select * from NUOC where MaNuoc = @MaNuoc)
        begin
            print 'Ma nuoc does not exist'
            return
        end
        else
        begin
            insert into TINH  
            values ('@MaTinh', '@TenTinh')

            insert into SQL_HOME.QLXNK.dbo.TINH 
            values ('@MaTinh', '@MaNuoc')

            print 'Inserted successfully ' + @TenTinh
        end
    end
end
GO
```

I have 2 tables in 2 different host which is TINH in local and the second is SQL_HOME.QLXNK.dbo.TINH

- Table1 (MaTinh char(4) primary key not null, TenTinh varchar(50))
- Table2 (MaTinh char(4) primary key not null, MaNuoc char(2))

When I execute

```
exec InsertTINH 'VN01','Ho Chi Minh','VN'
```

I get an error:

> String or binary would be truncated

but just insert normally --> it works!

```
insert into TINH 
values ('VN01', 'Ho Chi Minh')

insert into SQL_HOME.QLXNK.dbo.TINH 
values ('VN01','VN')
```

What is the problem in my stored procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove `'` around variables/parameters:

```
insert into TINH values (@MaTinh,@TenTinh)
insert into SQL_HOME.QLXNK.dbo.TINH values (@MaTinh,@MaNuoc)
```

`@MaTinh` - variable, `'@MaTinh'` - string

```
DECLARE @MaTinh char(4) = 'VN01';
SELECT @MaTinh, '@MaTinh';
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/YKPAW83092)**</kbd>

---

It is a good practice to specify column names in `INSERT` list:

```
INSERT INTO TINH(col_name1, col_name2) VALUES (@MaTinh,@TenTinh);
```

Comment: Oh GOD!! THANKS U SO SO SO MUCH!! I take 2 hours to figure it out but still get not thing.

Comment: I accept right a way and it said need 5 min to accept :)